# Wordpress show only text after the more-tag

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Is there any possibility to show only the content which comes after the more-tag. Could it work by using a special jQuery or php function?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$contentFull=get_the_content();
$contentSplit=explode("<!-more->",$contentFull);
$beforeMore=$contentSplit[0];
for ($i=1; $i<count($contentSplit); $i++) {
    $afterMore.=$contentSplit[$i];
}

?>
```

EDIT 1:

If you put more than mone more tag in your post, the $afterMore variable will now still contain the rest of your post.

Comment: Just for comprehension - i have to echo $contentSplit[0] for the text before the more-tag and $contentSplit[1] to load the text after it?